# Do nested Viewmodel If Binding with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, knockout.js

I want to calculate within an `if binding` from a nested view model.
I know how to do a standard `if binding` based on my view model:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: SelectedVendor() ? SelectedVendor().VendorPrice : '0'" /></td>
```

Now I want to do the Following:

1. If `QTYonOrder > SelectedVendor().VendorMOQ` then I want to display the `QTYonOrder`
2. If `QTYonOrder < SelectedVendor().VendorMOQ` then I want to display the `VendorMOQ`

Is it possible to do these calculation within the data-bind IF?

**My JSON Reply:**

```
   {
    "ProductName": "Product123",
    "RequiredComponents": "CAP 10% H/Vol",
    "StockCode": "142111411",
    "RequiredQtyByBom": 4,
    "QtyUnassignedInWarehouse": 0,
    "QtyAllocatedInWarehouse": 40,
    "PCBReference": "442C",
    "QtyOnOrder": 26,
    "Vendors": [],
    "RequireVendor": false
},
{
    "ProductName": "Product123",
    "RequiredComponents": "Screws",
    "StockCode": "Screws",
    "RequiredQtyByBom": 1,
    "QtyUnassignedInWarehouse": 0,
    "QtyAllocatedInWarehouse": 14,
    "PCBReference": "Screws",
    "QtyOnOrder": 26,
    "Vendors": [
                  {"VendorID": "3", 
                  "VendorName": "ABC Supplier",
                  "VendorMOQ": 50000,
                  "VendorItemPrice": 322},
                  {"VendorID": "4", 
                  "VendorName": "DEF Supplier",
                  "VendorMOQ": 4,
                  "VendorItemPrice": 120}
               ],
    "RequireVendor": true
},
{
    "ProductName": "Product123",
    "RequiredComponents": "14141415",
    "StockCode": "151555231",
    "RequiredQtyByBom": 1,
    "QtyUnassignedInWarehouse": 0,
    "QtyAllocatedInWarehouse": 170,
    "PCBReference": "1414",
    "QtyOnOrder": 26,
    "Vendors": [],
    "RequireVendor": false
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Stock Code</td>
                        <td>Qty Required</td>
                        <td>Vendor</td>
                        <td>Vendor Price p/Unit</td>
                        <td>MOQ</td>
                        <td>Qty To Order</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: CheckStock">
                    <tr data-bind="if: RequireVendor">
                        <td data-bind="text: StockCode"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: (RequiredQtyByBom * QtyOnOrder)">                         
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select data-bind="options: Vendors, optionsText: 'VendorName', optionsCaption: 'Choose a Vendor...', value: SelectedVendor" class="form-control"></select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: SelectedVendor() ? SelectedVendor().VendorPrice : '0'" /></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: SelectedVendor() ? SelectedVendor().VendorMOQ : '0'"></td>
                        <td>TODO CALC</td>
                        <td>TODO CALC</td>
                    </tr>                       
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Does it have to be calculated in the view? Seems more appropriate to create a `computed observable` in your `viewModel` for this.

Comment: That should work.  Please post your viewModel to make sure everything is right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're a colleague of the person that asked [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502540/419956). I'm re-using [the fiddle I posted there](http://jsfiddle.net/7m3F6/) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510836/419956), which utilizes the mapping plugin. As noted by @BradleyTrager in a comment, you haven't shown your ViewModel, so that's why I chose to reuse mentioned fiddle.

The logic you want to use in an `if` binding seems fine to me. However, because you'll need to accomodate for nothing being selected, the actual code would quickly contain too much logic to be healthy in a view (in pseudo code):

```
<!-- ko: if typeof SelectedVendor() != 'undefined' && 
            QtyOnOrder() < SelectedVendor().VendorMOQ() -->
```

Therefore I'd recommend adding it to your view model as a computed:

```
self.ShowMOQ = ko.computed(function() {
    if (typeof self.SelectedVendor() === 'undefined') { return true; }
    return self.QtyOnOrder() < self.SelectedVendor().VendorMOQ();
});
```

Then the View becomes quite clean:

```
<!-- ko if: ShowMOQ -->
```

Or:

```
<!-- ko if: !ShowMOQ() -->
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Pzs/) for a working demo.

Note that I don't (and can't) know if I've placed the bits in the correct spot in the fiddle, because your question contains a lot of code that isn't related to your question yet impossible to understand without context. Related to that I'd suggest making your examples in questions smaller ([as small as possible](http://sscce.org)), which makes it easier for others to answer and help.